# LLVM frontend supporting large integers

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

I'm currently looking for an LLVM frontend that supports large integers like `i128`, `i256` and `i512`. As far as I know rust and clang support `i128`, but nothing above.

Does such a frontend exist already or do I have to make my own?

Comment: Well, Haskell (GHC) has arbitrary precision integers and LLVM backend. Does that count as frontend?

Comment: It definitely a frontend, but unfortunately arbitrary precision integers are not implemented on LLVM level. I need actual `i128` etc. to appear in the LLVM IR. Sorry for being so vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently added into clang (In the upcoming Clang 12) is `_ExtInt(N)`, implementing [N2472](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2472.pdf) in C and C++.

Basically, the types `_ExtInt(N)` and `unsigned _ExtInt(N)` expose `iN` for arbitrary N in llvm. So you could use these:

```cpp
typedef _ExtInt(256) i256;
typedef _ExtInt(512) i512;
```

in the C or C++ frontends.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: However, modulus and division remains unimplemented.

Comment: They aren't implemented by the backends, but I only need the IR anyways.